# Copy-offset method not working

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub BSRange()

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Balance")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash")
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim colname As String
Lastcol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To Lastcol

  With ws1
    colname = Split(Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colname).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  With ws3
    Range(Cells(4, i), Cells(Lastrow, i)).Copy ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
  End With

  With ws1
    Range(Cells(4, i), Cells(Lastrow, i)).Copy ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  End With

Next i
End Sub
```

The data does not copy and the compiler shows no error in the code. Also,  when I try to get rid of `With` in the `For` loop, using `SheetName` in the prefix, then it gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with these edits. I think you just need to be more careful about qualifying worksheets when you are working across multiple. For instance `Cell()` will call on the active worksheet, `.Cells()` will call on the workbook qualified in you `With` statement.

```
Sub BSRange()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Balance")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash")
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim colname As String
Lastcol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To Lastcol

With ws1
colname = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colname).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With ws3
.Range(.Cells(4, i), .Cells(Lastrow, i)).Copy ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
End With

With ws1
.Range(.Cells(4, i), .Cells(Lastrow, i)).Copy ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

Next i
End Sub
```